# How to login via SSH without writing the IP address?

Tags: linux, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connect to Linux by name rather than IP](https://superuser.com/questions/185678/connect-to-linux-by-name-rather-than-ip)

When I login I always do:

```
ssh myuser@111.111.111.111
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
ssh myuser@server1
```

I would like to use a name, not an IP address, is it possible?

Comment: somewhat related to [Connect to Linux by name rather than IP](http://superuser.com/questions/185678/connect-to-linux-by-name-rather-than-ip)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a line to your ssh `config` file (often located at `~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host server1
  HostName 111.111.111.111
```

This could be considered a little neater than editing the `hosts` file as it's user-specific.

Comment: You can also specify many other parameters --- read `man ssh_config` for more info

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by adding the following line to the `/etc/hosts`

```
111.111.111.111 server1
```

below the line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

You need to be root to be able to do that.