# Connect to Beagle Bone Black by name (from Windows)

Tags: linux, networking, dns, beagleboard

I'm new to BBB, and my linux experience is limited. But I kind of thought changing the /etc/hostname file would be all I would need to do to connect to it by name.

I set the hostname file to LorenzBBB1, but cant ping LorenzBBB1 from the windows PC (or ping the windowsPC by name from the BBB). But can by IP address. (the BBB can also ping google.com just fine).

From a Linux PC (unbuntu) I'm able to ping LorenzBBB1.local (but only with the .local). And the BBB can only connect to the linux with the name.local as well.

All the widnows PCs on the network can ping each other by hostname no problem.

For this I conclude the mDNS is working, but for some reason the DHCP server is not updating the DNS records for the BBB?

Results from ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C8:A0:30:AD:EB:2F
      inet addr:192.168.1.109  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::caa0:30ff:fead:eb2f/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:47334 errors:0 dropped:856 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:664 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:5448097 (5.1 MiB)  TX bytes:68006 (66.4 KiB)
      Interrupt:56


lo          Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:16181 (15.8 KiB)  TX bytes:16181 (15.8 KiB)
```

Results from  journalctl | grep avahi

```
Oct 09 08:35:49 LorenzBBB1 avahi-daemon[124]: Server startup complete. Host name is LorenzBBB1.local. Local service cookie is 4096709841.
Oct 09 08:35:49 LorenzBBB1 avahi-daemon[124]: Service "LorenzBBB1" (/services/udisks.service) successfully established.
Oct 09 08:35:49 LorenzBBB1 avahi-daemon[124]: Service "LorenzBBB1" (/services/ssh.service) successfully established.
Oct 09 08:35:49 LorenzBBB1 avahi-daemon[124]: Service "LorenzBBB1" (/services/sftp-ssh.service) successfully established.
Oct 09 08:35:49 LorenzBBB1 avahi-daemon[124]: Service "Cloud9 IDE on LorenzBBB1" (/services/cloud9-avahi.service) successfully established.
Oct 09 08:35:53 LorenzBBB1 avahi-daemon[124]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.109.
Oct 09 08:35:53 LorenzBBB1 avahi-daemon[124]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 09 08:35:53 LorenzBBB1 avahi-daemon[124]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.109 on eth0.IPv4.
Oct 09 08:35:53 LorenzBBB1 avahi-daemon[124]: Registering new address record for fe80::caa0:30ff:fead:eb2f on eth0.*.
```

If I ping LorenzBBB1.local from the BBB it works, but LorenzBB1 it doesn't. Only the mDNS seems to work.

This is more of a how to get linux to play nice with domain names than a BBB question, but anyway I'm out of ideas on what to check.

I guess it could be an issues with the company router, but what configuration on a router could make lan dns not work for linux, but work fine on widnows?

Update:
results of  doing a du . | grep dhcp

```
8   ./etc/udhcpc.d
4   ./usr/share/common-licenses/busybox-udhcpc
4   ./usr/share/common-licenses/gadget-init-udhcpd
8   ./usr/share/udhcpc
```

Comment: Useful question.  For newbies like my self, modifying `hostname` requires rebooting or `systemctl restart avahi-daemon` so that `ping LorenzBBB1.local` works from Linux (Ubunto in my case). Still doesn't work from Windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for me at least was you need NetBIOS

The easiest way to get this seems to be install samba.

```
opkg install samba
```

On reboot it then just started working.

If anyone knows of or finds a lighter weight package than samba (all I need is the netBIOS) I'd be really interested in hearing about it.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the hostname you also need to update your dhcp client configuration file

Try adding the following steps

Open the dhcp client config file located at

`/etc/dhcp3/dhcpclient.conf`

Replace the current hostname or add to file if none exists

`send host-name "LorenzBBB1"`

And restart networking

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: BBB comes with the argstrom distro, and as you can see from my update I just didn't have a /etc/dhcp3. After a "opkg list | grep dhcp" I noticed a dhcp-client. I did "opg install dhcp-client", and got /etc/dhcp as a result (no dhcp3), and it had a dhcpclient.conf, I edited it as you suggested. and rebooted. No change in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning about this too, so forgive obvious answers.

The `*.local` pattern is served by the avahi-daemon service.  The `avahi` daemon only works with the Bonjour/Zeroconf/mDNS system, which not part of Windows by default, but it is on Apple and Linux typically.  You can install bonjour for Windows. See this link for ideas: [How can I resolve .local addresses in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/491747/how-can-i-resolve-local-addresses-in-windows)

I'm guessing that to get the BBB to work for everyone, I think you want to have *both* avahi and netBIOS running.