# unable to resolve linux hostname from windows pc

Tags: linux, windows, networking, dns, ping

I have a setup a web server on a pi running centos but I can't seem to resolve its hostname on any windows machines, either by pinging or typing the address into a browser.

I have tried from a mac and I can ping the centos pi.

I have tried from a debain linux machine and I can ping the centos pi.

I have tried pinging from two different windows 10 machines and both are unable to ping, command prompt tells me that `ping request could not find host`.

I have tried installing samba on the centos pi, because I was running out of ideas, which didn't seem to do anything, though I didn't setup any shares, instead I just enabled the default printer configuration.

interestingly, I am able to ping the debian linux machine using the hostname from a windows 10 machine, just not the centos pi. I don't remember having to do anything special to allow windows to be able to resolve the debain machines hostname.

I also set the hostname, in hostnamectl, on the centos pi, but it did nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please search earlier posts for "mDNS", "LLMNR", and "NBNS", for example https://superuser.com/questions/185678.

Comment: context? I don't understand. it already had a hostname (assigned by my router) and it works on all other platforms except windows.

Comment: The context is the 2nd half of your post. Hostnames don't just work by themselves – either your router has the hostname in its local DNS, or the host itself has to _announce_ it using one of these protocols (all of which are optional and might not be installed). For example if you found somewhere a suggestion to install Samba, that was for its NBNS support in "nmbd", not really for the shared folders.

Comment: Is your problem hostnames (unsolvable) or ping (maybe solvable)?

Comment: I can ping using an IP, but not by hostname.